# Полиморфизм подтипов

Tags: c#, ооп

Что из себя представляет полиморфизм подтипов в C#? Как его реализовать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Полиморфизм подтипов -- это то, что обычно понимают под полиморфизмом в объектно-ориентированном программировании. Он заключается в том, что вызывающий код использует объект, опираясь только на его интерфейс (контракт), не зная при этом фактического типа. Такой подход позволяет подтипам реализовывать свое поведение и т.о. изменять поведение программы без перекомпиляции кода-клиента. Возьмем пример из Википедии:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract String Talk();
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public override String Talk()
    {
        return "Meow!";
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override String Talk()
    {
        return "Woof!";
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static void Write(Animal animal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(animal.Talk());
    }

    public static void Main(String args[])
    {
        Write(new Cat());
        Write(new Dog());
    }
}
```

Здесь класс `Animal` -- это базовый тип, объявляющий интерфейс (контракт). Интерфейс состоит всего из одного метода. Далее у нас есть два дочерних класса -- `Cat` и `Dog`, каждый из которых переопределяет метод `Talk` своим собственным поведением, соответствующим этому классу.

Метод `Program.Write` является в данном случае клиентом -- он принимает на вход объект типа `Animal` и вызывает метод `Talk`. При этом он не знает ничего о фактическом типе объекта, а пользуется только объявленным интерфейсом. Подсовывая ему экземпляры разных типов -- `Cat` и `Dog` -- мы получаем разное поведение (на консоль выводится разный текст).